# Saving user input data after each use in Illustrator

Tags: path, illustrator-scripting

How can a make a .txt file to save user input data after each use?
I would like to save or store the "width" and "height" var until the next input.

```
        var doc = app.activeDocument;
        var panel = new Window("dialog", "test", undefined, { borderless: false });

        var row1 = panel.add ("group");
        row1.add ('statictext {text: "width", characters: 8, justify: "left"}');
        var width = row1.add("edittext",undefined, "100");
        width.characters = 10;
       
        var row2 = panel.add ("group");
        row2.add ('statictext {text: "height", characters: 8, justify: "left"}');
        var height = row2.add("edittext",undefined,"200");
        height.characters = 10;
        

        var row3 = panel.add ("group");
        row3.add("button", undefined, "OK");
        row3.add("button", undefined, "Cancel");
        panel.show();


        x = Number(width.text + " "); 
        i = Number(height.text + " ");
        
        var layer = doc.layers[0];
        var rectangle;
        rectangle = layer.pathItems.rectangle(0, 0, x, i);
```

Comment: I don't know if there are better ways to store persistent data these days, but a text file certainly works. [Here's some example code for reading and writing a text file](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/052cd9eaa42fe1272ff9c0bf5ee0e2d8). If you want to write more complex data than just 2 values, you might want convert a javascript object to JSON using `JSON.stringify( myVar )` and then `JSON.parse( text )`. JSON extension is `.json`. I think you still need to manually add JSON to your project to use the mentioned JSON methods, but I'm not sure if that's changed in the newer CC versions.

Comment: You can include [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js) in your script to use the JSON methods. Or you can write comma separated text and parse it yourself, like in this case you could save the text file contents as: `width,height` → `122,300` and read `text.split(',')`. — This might not be necessary looking at your dialog, but perhaps it's useful in the future... I have made a [ScriptUI dialog builder](https://scriptui.joonas.me/) that basically tries to solve the issue of designing the dialog and it also exports working javascript code for SUI.

Comment: @Joonas you can save the variables in illustrator settings Like         `app.preferences.setStringPreference('yourscript/subvalue',"data");`

Answer (score 1):

You can store and retrieve stuff from illustrator settings with:

```
app.preferences.setStringPreference('yournamespace/subvalue/subvalue', "text");
```

And read it with

```
app.preferences.getStringPreference('yournamespace/subvalue/subvalue')
```

The database is a key value storage. You can also read settings for other things like snapping or gridspacing.

A working example script that does storage and updating of the data can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/src/master/jooGraphFunction.jsx), yes I am the script author.

Comment: Thanks for reply
the "jooGraphFunction,", is too advanced for me
can you exemplify on  my script  to better understand?